How to conditionally enable providers injected by dynamic feature module
I am creating a dynamic feature module, and this module will be installed on demand.
My dynamic feature module uses some libraries that injects a <provider> in into the manifest.
So if I don't make any changes, my app will crash on launch because the provider. If I disable the provider in AndroidManifest.xml, how do I re-enable this provider when the module is installed?
